# Pass custom escape sequences from iTerm2 to Emacs

Tags: emacs, terminal, iterm2, ansi-escape

I spent quite some time reading about ANSI escape codes (e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), in particular the sequence on [generic format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes)) and how terminal emulators capture and translate key combinations into escape sequences (e.g. a great thread [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal)).

I (think I) understand that the escape sentence syntax allows for arbitrarily long private/non-standard escape sequences; in particular iTerm2 (a terminal emulator for macOS) has defined a set of proprietary escape sequences ([link](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html)).

First, am I right about private escape sequences?

And if so, is it possible (and then how) to define a private escape sequence, bind it to some key (say `Command-z`) in iTerm2, so that iTerm2 would not catch it and directly pass it to the active program (e.g. Emacs)?

The ultimate goal would be to allow Emacs to catch key combinations based on `Command` in a terminal emulator...

Comment: This answer seems to fix most issues with control characters in current versions of iTerm2: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56026/37528

Answer (score 1):

The escape sequences *recognized* by iTerm2 are irrelevant.  While special keys are often set up to send characters beginning with an <kbd>escape</kbd> character, those are actually not *escape sequences* (they have no meaning to the terminal).

What you want is done by configuring the keys/modifiers in iTerm2's preferences dialog to send characters that you can then configure Emacs to recognize.  Here is a screenshot of the preferences dialog:

[image: iTerm2 key-mappings]

In a different preferences dialog, you can tell iTerm2 to do different things (e.g., shortcuts to actions that may/may not already be on a menu):

[image: keys used to tell iTerm2 to do something]

Comment: I know these settings screens but I'm not sure what to do there based on your answer. Just to be clear, I don't want to bind Command to Meta or another existing key or key combination (I would know how to do this but that's not what I'm looking for).

Comment: Thanks for first key map screen. Option Left-Alt for "+Esc" fixed my nano M-M problem.